# How to link this node?

Tags: python, node-editor, shader-nodes

I have problem with linking this node to this one via Python script. My script can link ***"2"*** to ***"1"*** with One "Convert" click button but I can't understand to link this three nodes with one "Convert" button. It just link "2" to "1". What I need to do is:

1. Click "Convert".
2. Link 3 to 2, 2 to 1.

[image]

Here is the part of code for link 2 to 1:

> 

```
def convert_mat(material):
    if not material.use_nodes or not material.cshader.use_nodes:
        return
    node_tree = material.node_tree
    nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
    cycles_output = None
    cshader_output = None
    ymin = 100000
    ymax = -100000
    to_convert = []
    for node in nodes.values():
        if node.bl_idname.startswith("cshader"):
            cshader_output = node
            break
        if node.name == "CshaderPreviewNode":
            continue

        ymin = min(node.location[1] - node.dimensions[1], ymin)
        ymax = max(node.location[1], ymax)
        if node.bl_idname == "ShaderNodeOutputMaterial":
            cycles_output = node
            continue

        if node.bl_idname in node_map.keys():
            to_convert.append(node)

    # This node tree has been migrated already
    if cshader_output:
        return

    # We need a cycles output to copy
    if not cycles_output or not cycles_output.inputs[0].is_linked:
        return

    # Some padding
    ymin -= 100
    tex_output = nodes.new("CshaderTexNode")
    cshader_output = nodes.new("CshaderOutputNode")
    cshader_output.select = False
    cshader_output.location = [cycles_output.location[0], ymin - (ymax - cycles_output.location[1])]
    
    cshader_material = nodes.new("CshaderNode")
    cshader_material.select = False
    cshader_material.location = -162, -720
    cshader_material.width = 200
    cshader_material.bl_width_default = 200
    cshader_material.bl_width_min = 200 
    cshader_material.bl_width_max = 200
    node_tree.links.new(cshader_material.outputs[0], cshader_output.inputs[0])
```

I think this line will create and link 2 to 1. Am I right?

> 

```
node_tree.links.new(cshader_material.outputs[0], cshader_output.inputs[0])
```

If so, what am I must to do for solve my problem?
P.S.: Can I also create not with three node but with four nodes and last 4 is link to 3? And how>?